# On Spark, does Coalesce redistribute partitions or just merge them?

Tags: apache-spark

If lets say I have and rdd with 3 partitions, and I do a `coalesce(2)`.  My experience with spark is that it just clubs together partitions, and doesn't ever split any existing partition into multiple

```
  val data = List((1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3),(3,3),(3,4))
  val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
  val partitionedRdd = rdd.partitionBy(new org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner(3))
  partitionedRdd.saveAsTextFile("testPartition/partitioned")
  //$ cat partitioned/part-00000 
  //(3,3)
  //(3,4)
  //$ cat partitioned/part-00001 
  //(1,1)
  //(1,2)
  //$ cat partitioned/part-00002
  //(2,2)
  //(2,3)
  val coalescedRdd = partitionedRdd.coalesce(2)
  coalescedRdd.saveAsTextFile("testPartition/coalesced")
  //$ cat coalesced/part-00000
  //(3,3)
  //(3,4)
  //(2,2)
  //(2,3)
  //$ cat coalesced/part-00001
  //(1,1)
  //(1,2)
```

Is that guaranteed to keep happening?  Or it is just coincidence that the current implementation does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coalesce will, as you say, is guaranteed to just club together/merge partitions by default. Coalesce will not trigger a shuffle (redistribute) unless you specifically set `shuffle = True`

[From the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#coalesce(int,%20boolean,%20scala.math.Ordering))

> This results in a narrow dependency, e.g. if you go from 1000 partitions to 100 partitions, there will not be a shuffle, instead each of the 100 new partitions will claim 10 of the current partitions.

Comment: Just to be clear, a 'shuffle' is the only way a partition would break apart.  Merging partition explicitly means merging whole partitions.

Comment: Hmm. Shuffle refers to shuffling data across nodes on the cluster. So, I suppose it's theoretically possible to rearrange the partitions without shuffling the data across nodes. But, that seems like a convoluted way to implement `coalesce`. I think it's safe to assume the all of the data from a partition prior to `coalesce` will end up on the same partition. This quote from the link suggests that is the case `if you go from 1000 partitions to 100 partitions, there will not be a shuffle, instead each of the 100 new partitions will claim 10 of the current partitions`

Comment: To me this makes sense, except for sometimes when I coalesce I get really uneven partition sizes because you can't always put together pieces uniformly on a single node.  I wasn't questioning your answer's correctness, I was just confirming understanding.  Thanks